# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 Error: Cannot find module '.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.2.cjs'

Tags: yarnpkg

When I use the Yarn command, it always shows the error message:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.2.cjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Node.js v17.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Try to do the following:

1. Run `rm ~/.yarnrc`
2. Run `rm yarn.lock` and `rm .yarnrc.yml` (if these files exist) from your project's directory
3. Remove entry `"packageManager": "yarn@3.0.2"` from your `package.json`
4. Run `yarn install`

I found an explanation why this is happening here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8460